# jQuery mobile rules are not being applied

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile

This my index.jsp file but the jQuery mobile CSS and JS do not do their work.

[image]

My .css and .js files are at the same dir level as index.jsp. Should they be in a different directory? Here is my directory structure

[image]

Here is my index.jsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
            <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Firebug says that both resources are loaded

[image]

Comment: What does "not loaded" mean? Use a network traffic monitor (the one built into Chrome developer tools or Firebug for instance). Are the resources being requested? What status code are they returning? Does the content match what you expect? What do your server logs say?

Comment: By "not loaded" I mean the js & .css files are not being referenced.

Comment: The HTML source looks fine to me. Follow @David's comment. Is the browser requesting those files at all? Can you load the JS and CSS files directly (by typing the URL into the browser's URL bar)?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021290/referencing-javascript-libraries-with-tomcat/1022325

Comment: How do I check if resources are being requested using firebug ?

Comment: By the *Net* tab. Check the HTTP response status code. Successful results in 2nn/3nn (200 usually). Client errors results in 4nn (404 usually and they are red highlighted in firebug). Server errors results in 5nn (500 usually).

Comment: firebug results attached to question, everything looks to be loaded correctly ?

Comment: You need to load `jquery.js` as well. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is far from the reference page structure as shown [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html).

You should have the following wrapping your field-contain after your body:

```
<div data-role="page">
... your content in the body
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the a data-role="page" tag around the content as well as add the jQuery framwork

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to be loaded as well. Download it, put it in the same folder and add the following line *before* you load jQuery mobile.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but now no field is being displated on the page. I tried jQuery versions jquery-1.5.2.js & jquery-1.6.1.js but same result

Comment: Read the jQuery mobile documentation how to use it properly. Apparently your `data` attribute is incorrect or something.

Answer (score 0):

emmm you need to include them in the header of the file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='something.js'></script>
```

Comment: @user470, just replace `something` with your filenames

Answer (score 0):

while using jquery-mobile with  jsp's need to make sure you are using the cdn path

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
```